# shasum has no output, why?

Tags: macos, terminal

Here's the terminal command and output:

```
douglas@machine Desktop % shasum -a 256 /Users/douglas/Desktop/TinkerTool.app  
shasum: /Users/douglas/Desktop/TinkerTool.app: 

which shasum:
/usr/bin/shasum
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to `shasum` the downloaded TinkerTool.dmg not the TinkerTool.app!**

From https://www.bresink.com/osx/0TinkerTool/download.php under **Security Information** it states:

> To verify that the download package is authentic and has not been altered by a third party, you can verify its SHA-256 checksum.
>
> The SHA-256 checksum for the current version of the download file is ef148437af551bcce49e247610dfd4a1699cd6204057dc9feb0707f94096b9c1.

---

```
$ shasum -a 256 TinkerTool.dmg
ef148437af551bcce49e247610dfd4a1699cd6204057dc9feb0707f94096b9c1  TinkerTool.dmg
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Tinkertool.app is just a folder. You need to run it on the actual app. Your command should be shasum -a 256 /Users/douglas/Desktop/TinkerTool.app/Contents/MacOS/Tinkertool

You can get to the actual app by right-clicking on Tinkertool.app and selecting "Show package contents" and navigating to the actual app.

Comment: i added the correct answer. Sorry for the earlier mistake.

Answer (score 0):

> shasum

doesn't work on folders but works fine on files. Apps (i.e. *.apps) are essentially special folders which contain other files and folders. The actual executable besides all other necessary ressources usually is in: ApplicationX.app/Contents/MacOS/ and usually has the the name *ApplicationX*.

To shasum an app you would have to search for all **files** in this "app-folder" and execute shasum on them:

```
cd /Applications/Server.app/
find ./ -type f -print0  | xargs -0 shasum
```

The output is a very, very long list...

---

To verify a **downloaded** file you would have to `shasum` this file. The file may be a zip or a dmg file, which contains the app you will later install. To get the app you have to expand/unarchive the zip or mount the dmg and move the app to your Applications folder then.